# Incorrect use of static variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, static

Class A has a UIImage.

Class B has a static reference to a class of type A.

Before class B is instantiated, I want to call a static method in class B to assign an instance of class A.

```
+ (void)setClassAReference:(ClassA*)classA
{
    classA_ = classA;
}
```

Is this possible?

Before I delved into my current project, I created a sample one, and was able to set an integer value, then instantiate B with it keeping the stored value and allowing access to it.

However, in my current project, XCode refuses to allow me to pass an integer value:

Non-static method in class A:

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithIdentifier:(ImageIdentifier)identifier; // identifier is enum type
```

After class B is instantiated, I try to call a method in A:

```
UIImage *img = [classA_ imageWithIdentifier:ImageIdentifier_Foo];
```

But I get an implicit conversion warning.  The auto-complete  shows (id) instead of (ImageIdentifier).  I've triple-checked all my method signatures and they all use the enum type.

Am I using static variables incorrectly or is there another problem?  I realize I could use a singleton, but I'd prefer not to if possible.

I'm adding the enum declaration here:*

```
typedef enum
{
  ImageIdentifier_Foo = 0,
  ImageIdentifier_Bar
} ImageIdentifier;
```

*real names changed to protect the innocent.

Comment: Why does the _class_ `B` need to have a reference to an _instance_ of `A` before an _instance_ of `B` is created? Every instance of `B` will then have the _same_ instance of `A`.

Comment: 'A' holds a few different images used by several sub-classes of 'B.'  I want to make the classes re-usable, so each app might have different image names.  I want to avoid having each sub-class send the same image name each time one is created by only sending it once in a static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly...

If you want to initialize static variables on a class before it is instantiated you use the class method on NSObject

```
+ (void) initialize
```

This is where you can assign your static ClassA variable in ClassB.

Secondly....

Make sure you retain that classA variable, otherwise it will be released.

Thirdly.....

Regarding your implicit conversion... what is variable 'a', above this you wrote classA_. Can you show your enum declaration. Have you imported ClassA ?

I don't have any compile error with this:

ClassA.h

```
typedef enum
{
    ImageIdentifier_Foo = 0,
    ImageIdentifier_Bar
} ImageIdentifier;

@interface ClassA : NSObject

- (UIImage*)imageWithIdentifier:(ImageIdentifier)identifier; // identifier is enum type

@end
```

ClassA.m

```
#import "ClassA.h"

@implementation ClassA

- (UIImage*)imageWithIdentifier:(ImageIdentifier)identifier {
    return nil;
}

@end
```

ClassB.h

```
@interface ClassB : NSObject

@end
```

ClassB.m

```
#import "ClassB.h"
#import "ClassA.h"

static ClassA *classA;

@implementation ClassB

+ (void) initialize {
    classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
}

- (void) doSomething {
    UIImage *image = [classA imageWithIdentifier:ImageIdentifier_Foo];
    NSLog(@"image %@", image);
}

@end
```

Comment: Class A has it's own init method, which calls [super init] like any other class.  I'm not retaining, because I use ARC.  I made a mistake in my code, I changed the variable name for 'a'.  Yes, the class with type names are is imported.  Strangely, in class A, I now see errors in the interface method signatures 'Expecting a type' but header for the type is imported and the type name is in blue, clearly showing the compiler recognizes the type name. Add the enum declaration above.  What I'm doing should be possible correct?  Maybe XCode is being weird?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

The error got cleared up.

I was importing Class A in the .h file of Class B.  It was also being imported in the .m file of class B.  I removed the import in the .h file, and changed it to `@class ClassA` and everything automagically resolved itself.

Would a circular reference have caused this?

Comment: Dont think so. I just tried that with my sample code and still no problems.

Comment: I think Xcode just got screwed up then (wouldn't be the first time).  Thanks for your help.